# Resolver promesa mostrar solo array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promesas

He podido resolver la promesa que me devolvía

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(7)
```

Pero esta ves se me presento el inconveniente en cuanto al extraer la variable, en este caso result, el motivo de que quiero extraerlo es para almacenarlo en un useState de react.

Este es el código Actualizado

```
 const fsdasfda = db
    .collection("socios")
    .where("activity", "==", "true")
    .orderBy("num")
    .get()
    .then(function (query) {
      const array = [];
      query.forEach(function (doc) {
        const data = doc.data();
        array.push(data);
      });
      return array;
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });

  console.log(fsdasfda);
```

const [unidades, setUnidades] = useState(AQUI);

El console.log(result); me retorna los datos como quiero pasar al use state.
El console.log(fsdasfda); me retorna la promesa

Como mencione anteriormente deseo pasar el valor del RESULT al useState

Comment: Traduce pues estás en SO en español

Comment: Gracias estimado ya lo he corregido.

Comment: De verdad la estas ejecutando así, `console.log(fdsfsddsf);`, eso debería devolver una función no una promesa, si la estas ejecutando asi `console.log(fdsfsddsf())`; te esta respondiendo la promesa del método get de tu db

Comment: Ya he actualizado el código amigo pero se me presento otro inconveniente, la publicación ha sido actualizada.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de hooks de React, pero no podés obtener sincrónicamente el valor de una promesa. Una promesa define adentro una función, que es lo que se va a ejecutar cuando la promesa sea "resuelta". Por ende, es un dato que esperás/vas a tener en el futuro.
Tenés que buscar la forma de resolver tu setState asincrónicamente (esto es, encapsular el setState adentro del then de la promesa).
Sin saber nada sobre hooks, ¿no podés hacer algo así?

```
const fsdasfda = db
    .collection("socios")
    .where("activity", "==", "true")
    .orderBy("num")
    .get()
    .then(function (query) {
      const array = [];
      query.forEach(function (doc) {
        const data = doc.data();
        array.push(data);
      });
      return array;
    })
    .then((result) => {
      const [unidades, setUnidades] = useState(result);
    });
```

Si lo necesitás en otro lado del código, en vez de chainear el then ahí, podés usar "la variable" fsdasfda en esa parte:

```
const otraParteDeMiCódigo = () => {
    fsdasfda.then((result)=> {
        const [unidades, setUnidades] = useState(result);
    });
}
```

Lo digo sin haber leído de hooks. Quizás lo que le tenés que mandar al useState como parámetro debe ser (si o si) un valor sincrónico (ponele que lo necesites antes de renderizar, o algo así), y ahí deberías buscar otra alternativa.

Lo que SÍ te puedo garantizar es que no se puede obtener sincrónicamente el valor de una promesa. No hay ninguna forma de conocer en el presente lo que vas a tener en el futuro, salvo que seas Nostradamus jaja.

Sé que vas a intentarlo con await, pero tené en cuenta esto: una promesa abre un thread nuevo. Lo que lockea el await, es ese thread. La ejecución sigue. Más específicamente: Se vuelve sincrónico el thread. Ese thread se queda esperando la respuesta, pero tu código principal sigue corriendo en otro thread.

Tal vez no necesites usar ese valor en el useState().
Por qué no usás un useState() sin valor por default, y después en el resultado de la promesa le asignás un valor?

Algo así:

```
const miComponente = () => {
    const [unidades,setUnidades] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const result = await fsdasfda;
            setUnidades(result);
        }
        fetchData();
    });
}
```

¿No te sirve así?